# How to bind IDictionary in complex ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, model-binding

I've complex viewModel with dictionary field.

```
public class FieldViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Type { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Additional { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string, string> Options = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 

        public ViewState ViewState = ViewState.Save;

        public IList<SelectListItem> Types = new List<SelectListItem>();

        public static FieldViewModel BuildFieldVIewModel(Field fieldEntity = null)
        {
            FieldViewModel viewModel = new FieldViewModel();
            viewModel.Options.Add("key1","val1"); //just for test
            viewModel.Options.Add("key2","val2");
            if (fieldEntity != null)
            {
                viewModel.Id = fieldEntity.Id;
                viewModel.Type = fieldEntity.Type;
                viewModel.Name = fieldEntity.Name;
                viewModel.Additional = fieldEntity.Additinal;
                viewModel.ViewState = ViewState.Edit;
            }

            viewModel.Types = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FieldType)).Cast<FieldType>().Select(x => new SelectListItem {
            Value = ((int)x).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            Text = Enum.GetName(typeof(FieldType), x),
            Selected = fieldEntity != null && ((int)x) == fieldEntity.Id
            }).ToList();

            return viewModel;
        }
    }
```

And Razor view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Dictionary", FormMethod.Post))
{
    var index = 0;
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FieldId);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in Model.Options)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
           <input type="text" name="@string.Format("Options[{0}].Key", index)" value="@kv.Key" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" name="@string.Format("Options[{0}].Value", index)" value="@kv.Value" />
        </div>            </div>
        index++;
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Rendered html is

```
<form action="/Dictionary/1/Save" method="post"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field FieldId must be a number." data-val-required="The FieldId field is required." id="FieldId" name="FieldId" type="hidden" value="1">        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
               <input type="text" name="Options[0].Key" value="key1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" name="Options[0].Value" value="val1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
               <input type="text" name="Options[1].Key" value="key2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="text" name="Options[1].Value" value="val2">
            </div>
        </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

But in action method my dictionary is empty.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(FieldViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (viewModel.Options.Count == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Dictionary is empty.");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { fieldId = 1 });
}
```

Which name I must use for inputs for binding dictionary in viewModel correctly ?

Comment: Can you check and post the rendered markup for those fields (particularly the rendered name attributes)? This looks correct to me so I'm wondering if this is an issue with Razor escaping.

Comment: Just a second, I'll update question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Options = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

to

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Options {get;set;}
```

and add

```
Options = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

into your constructor.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Where I can find information about this trick? Must we use only properties for binding ?